# Android Thread Speed So Slow

Tags: android, multithreading, fft, audiorecord

I'm writing a program that listens for a certain frequency, and once it hears that frequency, it does something. I wrote the same program for iOS. The difference is, iOS would sample for the sound about 100 times per second. Android, on the other hand, samples about 8 times a second with up to a .4-second gap.

Here is the output:

```
09-09 11:59:48.532  21072-21389/...I/SETTT﹕ FREQ = 222.65625 MAG: 2.562424029452817
09-09 11:59:48.702  21072-21389/... I/SETTT﹕ FREQ = 324.21875 MAG: 16.865909238400896
09-09 11:59:48.773  21072-21389/... I/SETTT﹕ FREQ = 214.84375 MAG: 30.437427747561483
09-09 11:59:49.023  21072-21389/... I/SETTT﹕ FREQ = 175.78125 MAG: 38.29265030562946
09-09 11:59:49.063  21072-21389/... I/SETTT﹕ FREQ = 179.6875 MAG: 54.034422966799944
09-09 11:59:49.443  21072-21389/... I/SETTT﹕ FREQ = 203.125 MAG: 41.968567750551756
09-09 11:59:49.473  21072-21389/... I/SETTT﹕ FREQ = 242.1875 MAG: 46.684147052197986
09-09 11:59:49.503  21072-21389/... I/SETTT﹕ FREQ = 222.65625 MAG: 57.543877612425476
```

I need a very high amount of precision not only for beginning within .1 seconds of when the tone is heard, but also for the process after, which does something at every .0025 seconds (can be slightly off). On my iPhone 6 all of this is done very well.

Here is the relevant portion of the code (to signal that the tone was heard, I have the screen turn red):

```
private class Audio extends Thread {
        private boolean stopped = false;
        /**
         * Give the thread high priority so that it's not canceled unexpectedly, and start it
         */
        private Audio()
        {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.i("Audio", "Running Audio Thread");
            AudioRecord recorder = null;
            //short[][]   buffers  = new short[256][160];
            int ix = 0;

            /*
             * Initialize buffer to hold continuously recorded audio data, start recording, and start
             * playback.
             */
            try
            {
                /*
                int N = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N*10);
                byte[] buff = new byte[N];
                recorder.startRecording();
                */
                // 1 - Initialize audio
                int channel_config = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
                int format = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
                int bufferSize = 2048;
                int sampleRate = 8000;

                if (bufferSize < AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channel_config, format))
                    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channel_config, format);
                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, channel_config, format, bufferSize);

                // 2 - Get sound
                short[] signal = new short[bufferSize];
                recorder.startRecording();

                while(!stopped) {
                    //Log.i("Map", "Writing new data to buffer");
                    //short[] buffer = buffer[ix++ % buffer.length];
                    recorder.read(signal, 0, signal.length);
                    calculateFFT(signal);
                }

                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();


            } catch(Exception x)    {
                //Log.e("Audio", x.getMessage());
                x.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                //track.stop();
                //track.release();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Called from outside of the thread in order to stop the recording/playback loop
         */
        private void close()
        {
            stopped = true;
        }

    }



    public void calculateFFT(short[] signal)
    {
        int sampleRate = 8000;
        final int mNumberOfFFTPoints =1024;
        double mMaxFFTSample;

        double temp;
        Complex[] y;
        Complex[] complexSignal = new Complex[mNumberOfFFTPoints];
        double[] absSignal = new double[mNumberOfFFTPoints/2];


        for(int i = 0; i < mNumberOfFFTPoints; i++){
            temp = (double)((signal[2*i] & 0xFF) | (signal[2*i+1] << 8)) / 32768.0F;
            complexSignal[i] = new Complex(temp,0.0);
        }

        y = FFT.fft(complexSignal);

        mMaxFFTSample = 0.0;
        int mPeakPos = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < (mNumberOfFFTPoints/2); i++)
        {
            absSignal[i] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y[i].re(), 2) + Math.pow(y[i].im(), 2));

            if(absSignal[i] > mMaxFFTSample)
            {
                mMaxFFTSample = absSignal[i];
                mMag = mMaxFFTSample;
                mPeakPos = i;
            }
        }

        mFreq = (((1.0 * sampleRate) / (1.0 * mNumberOfFFTPoints)) * mPeakPos)/2;

        Log.i("SETTT", "FREQ = " + mFreq + " MAG: " + mMag);

        if (mFreq >= 696 && mFreq <= 704 && mMag >= 415) {
            mDidHitTargetFreq = true;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mBackgroundView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
                }
            });
        }
```

Instead of turning the screen red, I'd like to start a method that runs every .0025 seconds, but if android is so spotty in this, erroring by .4 seconds, how is this possible? Is a timer good enough or not? Is there also a way I can make the above listening process run more frequently (closer to 100 times per second, rather than 8?).

Is the listening process actually running very quickly and just the output is slow? Can I put the main thread to sleep somehow to make my listening thread run better? I'm not sure of what to do.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Traceview
[image]

Comment: Start by using Traceview and profile your app, to determine where your time is being spent. Also consider whether you are better served using C/C++ code (assuming OpenSL supports audio input).

Comment: Would the language of the code play a part? I'm new to Android but did not know I could even run C or C++ code on the device.

Comment: "Would the language of the code play a part?" -- yes. "did not know I could even run C or C++ code on the device" -- it is through [the Native Development Kit (NDK)](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). "Typically, good use cases for the NDK are CPU-intensive applications such as game engines, signal processing, and physics simulation"

Comment: I just edited my question to include a traceview screenshot.

Comment: That is not [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html).

Comment: OK, fixed it. Thanks.